# How to run GWT application in Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, gwt

i am new to gwt and i have installed gwt and created an new web application and just run the project in eclipse it works fine in google App engine and how can i make it run with tomcat..
because i have tomcat alone in my server...

Answer (score 3):

Just copy and paste contents of your WebRoot folder inside the webapps folder of your tomcat.
sorry for broken English.

Answer (score 3):

Make a .war file of your project and go to Tomcat Web Application Manager. Navigate to section *WAR file to deploy* choose your .war file and press deploy.

you can also check a nice tutorial on [how to make a .war file](http://blog.elitecoderz.net/gwt-and-tomcat-create-war-using-eclipse-to-deploy-war-on-tomcat/2009/12/).

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking for a general introduction, the GWT developer guide has a section on [deploying to a web server](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideDeploying.html#DevGuideDeployingWebServer) and some documentation on deploying applications to Tomcat is available [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/deployer-howto.html).

If you're encountering a specific problem or error, it would help if you could include more details.

Answer (score -1):

[Hosted Mode](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/FAQ_DebuggingAndCompiling.html#How_do_I_use_my_own_server_in_hosted_mode_instead_of_GWT%27s) not using built in jetty